# Filtering a dataframe

Tags: r

Still learning basic functions in R,
The subset function seems to only filter based a condition based on single column with or without multiple conditions?

How can I easily filter data from a dataframe?

1. when you are provided with multiple conditions
2. When the condition needs to be applied across the available columns.

Example:
Given a data frame containing

```
name    D1      D2     D3      D4
julius  "A"     "A"    "B"     "B"
cate    "D"     "E"     "A"     "C"
karo    "A"     "D"     "C"     "E"
```

say I want to filter this dataframe so that only names where any of the D1 to D4 is an 'E'
then I should have,

```
name    D1      D2     D3      D4
cate    "D"     "E"     "A"     "C"
karo    "A"     "D"     "C"     "E"
```

Say that the D1 can be a big list of columns, how or what is the recommended approach to perform this filter?
Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to combine several filters in **subset** function use logical operators:

```
 subset(data, D1 == "E" | D2 == "E")
```

will select those rows for which either column D1 or column D2 has value "E". Look at the help pages for available logical operators:

```
 > ?"|"
```

For your second question what you need is to filter the rows. This can be achieved in the following way

```
 collist <- c("D1","D2","D3","D4")
 sel <- apply(data[,collist],1,function(row) "E" %in% row)
 data[sel,]
```

The first argument to **apply** suplies the columns on which we need to filter. The second argument is 1, meaning that we are looping through rows of the data. The third argument is unnamed one-line function which returns **TRUE** if "E" is present in the row and **FALSE** if the "E" is not present.

The result of the apply function will be logical vector **sel**, which has the length the same as number of rows in data. We then use this vector to select the necessary rows.

**Update**

The same can be achieved with grep:

```
sel <- apply(data[,collist],1,function(row) length(grep("E",row))>0)
```

in R **grep** with default arguments returns the numbers of elements in the supplied vector which have the matching pattern.

Comment: another useful function is `any`. For instance if you want to check that at least one element of a vector is `= 10` you could write (`any(v==10)`).

Comment: @nico yeah, but **10 %in% v** has 9 characters and variant with **any** 10 :). Although for numeric vectors it is better to use equality, since R is smart and if your data is integers mixed with real numbers it will correctly recognize that you have 10 in your data set.

Comment: what about the case for regular expression? assuming that you do not want to work with an exact match? Do they have something close to ~= as in other languages? what is most close  to that expression in R

Comment: @Biorelated See `grep` and `agrep`, and related documentation on POSIX 1003.2 or Perl-compatible regex.

Comment: @Biorelated, I've update the answer with the example of grep.

Comment: Thanks a tonne on this!!!! the explanation and the references! awesome.