# How do I call nonconsecutive rows in an R dataframe?

Tags: r

Still learning basic syntax in R. Basic example code is provided below.

I know how to call consecutive rows but what if, for example, I wanted the 1st and 3rd row? Or better yet, since that is easily called by w[-2,] in this example,  what if the data set was larger and I had the need to investigate the 3rd, 5th and 8th row?

```
> w<-data.frame(names=c("betty","freddy","sammy"),high.fiving.ability=c(50,50,100))
> w[2:3,]
   names high.fiving.ability
2 freddy                  50
3  sammy                 100
```

BTW I looked at other posts including this one: [Filtering a dataframe](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6187/filtering-a-dataframe) but what I am looking for is even more basic than that.

Comment: You should start with some introduction to R! Here you wanna look at the `c` function. (solution `w[c(3,5,8),]`) I like Maindonald & Braun (2010): http://www.amazon.com/Data-Analysis-Graphics-Using-Example-Based/dp/0521762936/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: This is a perfectly good question, but because it's only about how to get `R` to do something, & not about any statistical issues (possibly w/ R), it belongs on Stack Overflow, not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index using a vector of indices of only the rows you care about.  In this case what you're looking for is

```
w[c(3, 5, 8), ]
```

Comment: Probably worthwhile to add that you can also put logical conditions here as well.  One generic one that I find particularly useful is "list[!(list %in% names(dataframe))]" which gives you all of the values in "list" which are not columns in "dataframe" - saves doing a manual scan, especially if you used capitals for one name and not the other.